# Firebase throw NullPointerException on ConnectionTracker bindService

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

i got this crashlog in the Play Console, it's happening in a variety of devices in Android version 8.0 and 9.0.

It's only implemented the Notifications section, the core and messaging library and we are just asking for the token.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at com.google.android.gms.common.stats.ConnectionTracker.bindService (ConnectionTracker.java)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.zzad.a (zzad.java:82)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.zzab.a (zzab.java:48)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.zzat.a (zzat.java:26)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.zzs.run (zzs.java:8)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at this [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Thank you, but this NullPointerException is not in own side, is in the firebase code but i don't know if i implemented something wrong.

Comment: I'm getting this also - only on huawei devices.  saw this issue reproted twice on github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk Google closed with out resolving :-(